# Print only the number of failed examples with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to make `rspec` just print number of failed examples without any other information?

I want the output to be like this:

```
Finished in 2.35 seconds (files took 7.33 seconds to load)
1207 examples, 40 failures, 15 pending
```

Thank You

Comment: You could pass the rspec output through `grep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box RSpec does not have a formatter that matches the output you want. However, it is possible to write your own formatter.

Here's is what it would look like for RSpec 3+

```
RSpec::Support.require_rspec_core "formatters/base_text_formatter"

class SimpleFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::BaseTextFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_passed, :example_pending, :example_failed, :dump_pending, :dump_failures, :dump_summary

  def example_passed(message)
    # Do nothing
  end

  def example_pending(message)
    # Do nothing
  end

  def example_failed(message)
    # Do nothing
  end

  def dump_pending(message)
    # Do nothing
  end

  def dump_failures(message)
  end

  def dump_summary(message)
    colorizer = ::RSpec::Core::Formatters::ConsoleCodes

    output.puts "\nFinished in #{message.formatted_duration} " \
       "(files took #{message.formatted_load_time} to load)\n" \
       "#{message.colorized_totals_line(colorizer)}\n"
  end
end

# Example from RSpec Core - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/bc1482605763cc16efa55c98b8da64a89c8ff5f9/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb
```

Then from the command line run `rspec spec/ -r ./path/to/formatter -f SimpleFormatter`.

To avoid having to type out the `-r` and `-f` options constantly, you can place them in your `.rspec`

```
--require ./path/to/formatter
--format SimpleFormatter
```

Now just running `rspec spec/` will automatically use the formatter we just created.

Comment: Thank you this is very close to what I want. There are also some other text displayed on screen beside just number of failing examples using the formatter you provided. Is it possible to get rid of them completely and only display the text that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Can you paste the extra text you are seeing?

Comment: Alright I've updated my code to hopefully just keep the bit you wanted